# Installing custom font in JetBrains PyCharm?

Tags: fonts, editor, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

How does one install a different font into PyCharm to use in the code editor?

The default font choices seem pretty limited and some of those fonts are not rendered properly.

Also, which font do you prefer to use in PyCharm?

Comment: IDE uses fonts installed on your system. So ... just install your font system wide (so it's available in other apps) and it should also be available in PyCharm. P.S. AFAIK PyCharm reads list of fonts only once (when you requesting it for first time) .. so you may need to restart IDE if you install font while IDE was running.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install the font you want then close out the program, open it back up and go t `File > Settings > Appearance And Behavior > Appearance`, click "Override Default Fonts", look for your font, and click apply then Ok.

Comment: this does not  work anymore, I installed SF fonts but they are not appearing in the drop down.

Comment: It's better to go to Editor -> Font. And don't forget to turn off checkbox about monospace fonts

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems all installed system fonts are available (Windows 10).
Even if I use some weird font, it renders ok.
I stay with default Segoe UI and for code I use Consolas.

[image: font settings]